# Using SQL or PL/SQL to parse an XML document to extract field values

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

I have a table that has the following columns

```
col1    varchar2
col2    varchar2
col3    varchar2
col4    clob
col5    varchar2
col6    varchar2
col7    varchar2
col8    varchar2
```

col4 is a `CLOB` type field which contains an xml document (note: not an xmltype) that is in the following format

```
<document>
    <type>DocumentType</type>
    <authors>
        <author>Author1</author>
        <author>Author2</author>
        <author>Author3</author>
    </authors>
    <documentDate>01JAN2014</documentDate>
    <publishedCountries>
        <country>country1</country>
        <country>country2</country>
    </publishedCountries>
</document>
```

I would like to do run a select statement to display all teh values from both the normal columns and from the XML document. 
I would like to know how can i write a query that can give the output in two structuers(ie. either one of the following structures)

Structure 1

```
col1  col2  col3    col5  col6  col7  col8  type          authors                     documentDate  publishedCountries
xx    xx    xx      xx    xx    xx    xx    DocumentType  Author1, Author2, Author3   01JAN2014     country1,country2
```

Structure 2 (i.e. the lists are not comma separated but are in individual columns)

```
col1  col2  col3  col5  col6  col7  col8  type          author   author   author  documentDate  country   country
xx    xx    xx    xx    xx    xx    xx    DocumentType  Author1  Author2  Author3 01JAN2014     country1  country2
```

I have been trying out the first one and this is what i have so far

```
select col1,    col2,   col3,   col5,   col6,   col7,   col8,
extract(xmltype(col4), '//type').getStringVal() type,
extract(xmltype(col4), '//authors').getStringVal() authors, 
extract(xmltype(col4), '//documentDate').getStringVal() documentDate, 
extract(xmltype(col4), '//publishedCountries').getStringVal() publishedCountries,
```

The above query does work but is limited to the following

- The lists are not comma separated
- The tags are still displayed

I think the second structure is slightly more difficult as i dont really know how to insert the value from a tag into a new column. I would like to preferable do this is just SQL as in the above query but if it is easier using a PL/SQL block then that is fine too.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

### Edit

I a struggling to align the column values in the two output examples i have provided. Basically the difference between the two is that in the first example, the list items from the XML is a comma separated value in one single column. In the second example, the list items are each in their own individual column.

Comment: The formatting issues you were struggling with were caused by the hard tabs in the text. Replacing the tabs with spaces corrected the problems. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for resolving that.

Comment: So the second structure is not "hard" but one that doesn't make sense if the number of authors can vary. For the first format you need to us analytic functions (more specifically - aggregation. I would recommend you to not look on this issue as an xml related, but of a "nested table" related, which will make it easier for you to create the format that you want. Migrating an xml to a nested table like format is also easy. let me know if you're still having trouble (it's a lot of code to write and simulate now, and I'm a bit tired, so I'll try to help more tomorrow)

Comment: Yes i agree. The second one will be more tricky to process. I will try and google how to use xml as nested table. If you could provide an example that would be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table called junk with the mentioned columns and data and the below select seems to work to get the data as comma separated lists.  Not sure about how to get them into separate fields though.

`select  j.col1, j.col2, j.col3, j.col5, j.col6, j.col7, j.col8, x.* 
from junk j,
XMLTABLE ('$d' passing xmltype(col4) as "d" 
   COLUMNS 
   type     varchar2(100)   PATH '//type/text()',
   authors  varchar2(100)   PATH 'fn:string-join(//authors/author/text(), "; ")',
   documentDate varchar2(100) PATH '//documentDate/text()',
   publishedCountries varchar2(100) PATH 'fn:string-join(//publishedCountries/country/text(), "; ")') AS x;`

Hope this is helpfull